# Why some utorrent files are very slow in downloading?

Tags: web, utorrent

Why some utorrent downloading take more time although we have huge speed??

I am downloading a movie from last 1 month which is 97% completed and in that time span i completed downloading 50+ other movies by using utorrent.

Is there any issue with some files or has some other issue?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Along with seeders see the maximum downloading speed for the torrent file.
Make sure you also cap your upload limit at 1kbps.

Comment: Actually this will often hurt you more than help. Most torrent clients have a "tit-for-tat" system that detects if someone they are uploading to has not uploaded very much it will limit the rate they send data. You should set a upload limit, but set it to a reasonable number, not 1 Kbps. Imagine trying to download a file from 20 seeds and all of them had the limit set to 1 Kbps, you would only download at 20 Kbps (which could be the problem for your slow download, you can only connect to a few seeds and they are very limited).

Comment: So i always go for torrentthound

Comment: Its not your torrent client that does the limiting, its the person who you are downloading from is limiting how fast he is sending to you if he detects that you are not uploading "your fair share".

Answer (score 7):

It could be because there aren't many seeders to download the file from, or the seeders that are available are low-quality/bandwidth limited.

It's generally a good idea to review how many active seeders there are before downloading something from bittorrent for just this reason.

Answer (score 0):

first of all I suggest you to first search your problem on google after you should come here. And the reason behind your slow downloading speed is less number of [Seeders and Peers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_BitTorrent_terms). If more and more persons upload your data then you'll get good speed. I suggest you to have patience may be after sometime people starts uploading or you can find any other healthy torrent for that file.